# Making equal height <div> tags

Tags: css, html

I wanted to make two divs to be equal in height , yes from various forums and blogs i found the way of doing that. Though i made it work still these CSS rules(mentioned in query part) are bothering me and doesn't seems to be understandable.
here's the mark up:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-col">
        Hello there , This is Left content<br/>
        Hello there , This is Left content<br/>
    <div>

    <div class="right-col">
        Hello there , This is right content<br/>
        Hello there , This is right content<br/>
        Hello there , This is right content<br/>
        Hello there , This is right content<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS :-

```
.container{
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

.left-col{
width:50%;
float:left;
padding-bottom:500em;
margin-bottom:-500em;
}

.right-col{
width:50%;
float:left;
padding-bottom:500em;
margin-bottom:-500em;
}
```

Query-
 Can somebody explain the working of

```
padding-bottom:500em (or something)
```

&

```
margin-bottom:-500em(Use of negative sign).
```

Comment: class="left-col" and  .left-container are different, first change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding-bottom property specifies the width between the element's content and the bottom border, represented by the yellow highlighted area in the illustration below.
[image]

Default value is 0, It can be defined in percentage, pixel, pt or em.

The margin-bottom property specifies the width between the element's bottom border and the element's outer edge, represented by the yellow highlighted area in the illustration below
[image]

The [definitions for units are](https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent):

> **“Ems” (em):** The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance,
> if the font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems
> are scalable in nature, so 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt,
> etc. Ems are becoming increasingly popular in web documents due to
> scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.
>
> **Pixels (px):** Pixels are fixed-size units that are used in screen media (i.e. to be read on the computer screen). One pixel is equal to
> one dot on the computer screen (the smallest division of your screen’s
> resolution). Many web designers use pixel units in web documents in
> order to produce a pixel-perfect representation of their site as it is
> rendered in the browser. One problem with the pixel unit is that it
> does not scale upward for visually-impaired readers or downward to fit
> mobile devices.
>
> **Points (pt):** Points are traditionally used in print media (anything that is to be printed on paper, etc.). One point is equal to
> 1/72 of an inch. Points are much like pixels, in that they are
> fixed-size units and cannot scale in size.
>
> **Percent (%):** The percent unit is much like the “em” unit, save for a few fundamental differences. First and foremost, the current
> font-size is equal to 100% (i.e. 12pt = 100%). While using the percent
> unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for
> accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

One nice way to solve this would be to automatically set height of both divisions using jQuery.

For example, let us say you have:

```
<div class="double_column_left">
    //code
</div>
<div class="double_column_right">
    //code
</div>
```

After that retrieve the height of one div '.double_column_right' and apply it to another div ('.double_column_left')'s min-height. Use the following JQuery code:

```
var divHeight = $('.double_column_right').height();

$('.double_column_right').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
```

Try this and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Well that's what i was looking for thnx .

Comment: @Ajaz No problem. Since you found this answer useful, could you click "accept"/"tick" for this answer?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, thats why I post this as an answer.
I recently had the same problem and found this:
http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc

Answer (score 0):

padding refers to the space within the container. It works from the outside in.
margin refers to the space outwards from that object to the next or the edge of the screen.

For example, if you had a box that is 100px sq. and you gave it a padding-bottom:-20px. Your content inside the box will be 20px away from touching the bottom of the box

If you gave the same box a margin-bottom:20px, anything else you place under the box will always be 20px away from it

I hope that answers your question

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZA2t/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-col">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right-col">RIGHT</div>
       <div class="clear">
          <p>I HAVE A MARGIN</p>
       </div>
    <div id="full-row">I HAVE PADDING</div>

</div>
```

I prefer to ID my containers and CLASS my container elements. That way I can use nesting and target any container I need to modify without creating too many classes. But that is up to you.

[image: **HERE IS THE OUTPUT**]

Comment: yes i get that it helped me.
Do you have any other solution to make equal heights of div.
Thanx anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this JQuery plugin on a couple of occasions and may work for you, especially as both columns can be the same height based on the columns contents.

It's by Adam Wulf and can be found at http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/.